# Web service running on windows parallels accessible by same machine (mac) but not by colleagues on the intranet

Tags: parallels

I just wrote a hello world application with Vaadin. The development was done on windows 10 running on parallels and I left the web service running on the windows virtual machine. I can access the service from a browser on windows through the url: localhost:8080/hello-world. I found out the IP address of the windows virtual machine with ifconfig and, if I type the url: ipaddress:8080/hello-world on a browser running on the mac, it works as well. However, my colleagues on the intranet cannot access the web application through the same url. What am I missing here? Is the service only visible to me? Are there any firewall issues? Setup problems with the parallels virtual machine?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: is your colleague able to ping `ipaddress`?

Comment: No. We just tried that. How can I make it visible?

Comment: then your colleague and you are not on same intranet. Check with your system admin

Comment: We are on the same intranet, because I can ping his mac and he can ping my mac, but he can't ping my windows running on parallels. Only my mac can ping it. I even turned off the firewall both for the windows machine on parallels and my mac. Please, note how I got the IP address from my windows on parallels, just with ipconfig. It seems OK with me, but I'm not a network guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer, but sidgate, thanks for your help. The bottomline is that I was running the windows virtual machine in shared mode. Apparently, if you do that, the windows virtual machine is in a subnet with your own mac, and the mac is the router. I switched to the bridge method with the default adapter and I then get an ip address on my intranet, which is visible by everyone.

Regards